# Django three model which should be connected and depends of other

Tags: django, django-models

I can't wrap my head how to store / define the right model / relationship.

I have following data:

[image: data visualization]

CATEGORY is their own model because i like to view / request in some situation *only* the category. But to this category I want set VALUE which I can only define onetime depending ON YYYY-MM.

What make me difficult to achieve / understand how i get the relationship between VALUE <-> YYYY-MM but still maintain the connection / dependency to only one CATEGORY "Rent".

Comment: Does each `Category` have only 1 `Value` and 1 `YYYY-MM`?

Comment: Each Category can have multiple VALUE + YYYY-MM but only together (like in the image)

Comment: Something about this structure feels off. Usually catogery is an EnumField on some Model. Is this some budgeting app? I feel like this can be done in one Model in more straightforward way

Comment: It's a new project by me to learn django and yes should result in a budget app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at doing something like this. You have two models with a foreign key, and  value and YYYY-MM are attributes of the model with the foreign key.

```py
class Category(models.model):
  pass

class TimePeriod(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["category", "start_date"], 
                name="unique_start_date_per_category"
            ),
        ]
```

EDIT: Add UniqueConstraint

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this now but i was still able so save multiple "Values" on the same Category AND Start date 

```
| Category | Value | Date |
|  ---  |  ---  |  ---  |
| Test | 100 | 2022-02-22 |
| Test | 150 | 2022-02-22 |
| Test | 200 | 2022-02-22 |
```

It should not be possible that Category Test can have multiple values for the same day.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Will update answer now.

Comment: Added a UniqueConstraint, that should do it :)